# Get imagery for a rectangle in Google Static Maps API

Tags: google-maps

I have two LatLong points: the upper left and bottom right points of a rectangle and I would like, using the Google Maps API, to retrieve satellite imagery for this rectangle.

I understand that since the zoom level is an integer I might not be able to get this exact rectangle but there's no problem if I get a bigger pixmap as long as I am able to calculate the bounding box for the pixmap in latlong coordinates.

Since the pixmap size is fixed (let's say 640x640) and I have it's center, how to find the appropriate zoom level and calculate the bounding box for the pixmap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a python reference linked in the old Google Maps API blog that provides the function CalculateBoundsZoomLevel.

The source file is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20080531035310/http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-examples/source/browse/trunk/nonjslocalsearch/localSearch.py).

```
  def CalculateBoundsZoomLevel(self, bounds, view_size):
    """Given lat/lng bounds, returns map zoom level.

    This method is used to take in a bounding box (southwest and northeast 
    bounds of the map view we want) and a map size and it will return us a zoom 
    level for our map.  We use this because if we take the bottom left and 
    upper right on the map we want to show, and calculate what pixels they 
    would be on the map for a given zoom level, then we can see how many pixels 
    it will take to display the map at this zoom level.  If our map size is 
    within this many pixels, then we have the right zoom level.

    Args:
      bounds: A list of length 2, each holding a list of length 2. It holds
        the southwest and northeast lat/lng bounds of a map.  It should look 
        like this: [[southwestLat, southwestLat], [northeastLat, northeastLng]]
      view_size: A list containing the width/height in pixels of the map.

    Returns:
      An int zoom level.
    """
    zmax = 18
    zmin = 0
    bottom_left = bounds[0]
    top_right = bounds[1]
    backwards_range = range(zmin, zmax)
    backwards_range.reverse()
    for z in backwards_range:
      bottom_left_pixel = self.FromLatLngToPixel(bottom_left, z)
      top_right_pixel = self.FromLatLngToPixel(top_right, z)
      if bottom_left_pixel.x > top_right_pixel.x :
        bottom_left_pixel.x -= self.CalcWrapWidth(z)
      if abs(top_right_pixel.x - bottom_left_pixel.x) <= view_size[0] \
          and abs(top_right_pixel.y - bottom_left_pixel.y) <= view_size[1] :
        return z
    return 0
```